# MailItem first modification time

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I would like to capture date and time when an email was FIRST modified after its creation (e.g. a category tag was added to it). Is it possible to add a `FirstModificationTime` property to `MailItem object` - similar to the existing `LastModificationTime`? How to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a User Property.

With FieldChooser | User-defined fields, you can manually create the user-defined field FirstModificationTime or once you run this you can add the automatically created field to the folder view.

```
Sub UserProp_FirstModificationTime()

    Dim myItem As mailitem
    Dim myUserProperty As UserProperty

    Set myItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set myUserProperty = myItem.UserProperties.Add("FirstModificationTime", olText)

    ' If you use a trigger event for this it will update once only.
    If myUserProperty.Value = "" Then
        myUserProperty.Value = Now
        myItem.SAVE
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

That would be `MailItem.CreationTime`.

Comment: That's the creation time. What I meant is that I would like to capture the time when I modifiy a received email for the first time. For instance, I get an email and tag it with a color category. The tagging time would be the first modification time.

Comment: There is no such thing - the first modification is the email creation. The last modification is LastModificationTime. The underlying message store does not know who is modifying the email or why - because a POP3 provider just downloaded the email? Or because the end user set a category? The store does not know and does not care.